# What happens to tagging after graduation?

Tags: discussion, tagging

Recently I am trying hard to organize and improve tags, and it came to my mind: is any effort worthwhile for e.g. removing the occasionally introduced nonsensical ones? Would tagging be restricted after graduation? Will the set of tags that we establish up to graduation be the standard set and no new tags can be introduced? Or if not, who would be able to introduce new tags? Should we focus more on establishing synonyms than on pruning unwanted tags?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at [TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation), I'm guessing we'll have the following changes related to tags:

- 300 rep to create a new tag (currently 150)
- 500 rep to retag (currently 200)
- 5000 rep to approve/reject tag wiki edits (currently 1500)

Comment: I find 300 a bit low for introducing new tags: this will mean that new and possibly redundant or half-baked tags will pop up from time to time to confuse users. Let's just hope for now that this won't be a really widespread issue.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that after graduation the standard Privilege levels will be in effect, and it will take [1500 Reputation to create tags](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/create-tags).

I further believe that questions will remain tagged as they are, and you efforts are not in vain.

Comment: This is what I believe too, though I haven't seen it in writing.

Comment: Mr.Wiz and @SjoerdC.deVries No, 1500 is only for [so]. Over here, it's merely 300 when graduated (of which, 101 is given for free if you're elsewhere in the network) and we should still watch out for new and arbitrary tags